# NSUserDefaults key initialization when app starts for the first time

Tags: ios, swift, crash, initialization, nsuserdefaults

If I start an app for the first time, the boolean key for a `NSUserDefaults` is `nil` and the app crashes when it tries out the state of the setting in an `if`-statement.

I try to initialize the key in `viewDidLoad()` as follows but the key seems to keep undefined:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if (defaults.objectForKey("fasterDemo") != nil) {
    defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "fasterDemo")
}
```

The fasterDemo key can be changed over a switch on a second view. The the views in the storyboard are controlled in two classes in `ViewController.swift`.
Additional the code in which I try to read out the state as an parameter for a timer.

```
let demo = defaults.stringForKey("fasterDemo")
var timerSpeed: Double = 1

if (demo! == "1") {
    timerSpeed = 0.001
}
else {
    timerSpeed = 1
}

timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timerSpeed, target: self, selector: Selector("countdownTimer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

I’m not so experienced in Xcode (not to say: I’m a beginner).
Thanks for your support!

Comment: `if (defaults.objectForKey("fasterDemo") == nil)` *

Comment: also, if you set a bool, don't read a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if (defaults.objectForKey("fasterDemo")) {//no need to use '==nil'
    defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "fasterDemo")
}
```

and,

```
let demo = defaults.boolForKey("fasterDemo")
var timerSpeed: Double = 1

if (demo) {//same as 'demo == true'
    timerSpeed = 0.001
}
else {
    timerSpeed = 1
}

timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timerSpeed, target: self, selector: Selector("countdownTimer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Note the `stringForKey` has been replaced with `boolForKey`

Comment: I tried `boolForKey` but did't bring the if-check to run: `demo! == "1"`: Operand of postfix "!" should have optional type; type is 'Bool'.

Comment: sorry, see edit. Your if statement was checking against a string and not a boolean

Comment: also change `demo!` to just `demo`

Comment: thank you very much, jammycoder! what would do the "!" at this point?

Comment: The `!` shows a value cannot be optional (nil value). More about it here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html I'm just about getting my head around it too

Comment: For example the code would also work as `let demo : Bool! = defaults.boolForKey("fasterDemo")...` then `...if (demo!)...` but demo must have a value (non nil) otherwise a runtime error is triggered

Answer (score 1):

Your logical test `!= nil` is the wrong way around - if it's `==` nil your want to set the default.

Anyway, what you should be doing is using `registerDefaults:` to set a complete dictionary of default values when the app starts. If the values are already set to something explicit then they won't be updated, if they aren't then the registered defaults are a transient (not saved / synchronised) setting for the app to use.